# OpenXML linechart from datatable

Tags: .net, excel, datatable, openxml, linechart

I am producing a report which is generated on page load of a web page based on query string. I have the cell data generating exactly as I would like it to in the spread sheet. Now I need to add a line chart. The data is dynamic and row count varies.

There is no information following searches, that is relevant to doing a openXML linechart in .net, so I have tried to follow the bar chart example, which takes a dictionary as a datasource, and tried to hack this so it will make a linechart from a dataTable.

The Linechart appears in the worksheet where I want it to, and it is adding the series based on column1 of the datatable. I want each point to be based on columns 2 to 13, but I only get column13, and the point names are not added.

I'll be honest I hate Excel and spreadsheets, and know little about them, and have little time to learn. This is my code so far for trying to add the data:

```
For i As UInteger = 0UI To CUInt(dataTable.Rows.Count - 2) 

    Dim seriesName As String = dataTable.Rows(CInt(i))(dataTable.Columns(CInt(0)).ColumnName).ToString()
    Dim lineChartSeries As LineChartSeries
    lineChartSeries = lineChart.AppendChild(New LineChartSeries(New Index() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(i)}, New Order() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(i)}, New SeriesText(New NumericValue() With {.Text = seriesName})))

    For j As UInteger = 1UI To CUInt(dataTable.Columns.Count - 3) 

        Try
            Dim pointName As String = dataTable.Columns(CInt(j)).ColumnName
            Dim pointValue As Integer = CInt(dataTable.Rows(CInt(i))(pointName))

            Dim strLit As New StringLiteral
            strLit.Append(New PointCount() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(1UI)})
            strLit.AppendChild(New StringPoint() With {.Index = New UInt32Value(1UI)}).Append(New NumericValue(pointName))
            lineChartSeries.AppendChild(New CategoryAxisData()).AppendChild(strLit)

            Dim numLit As New NumberLiteral
            numLit.Append(New FormatCode("General"))
            numLit.Append(New PointCount() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(1UI)})
            numLit.AppendChild(New NumericPoint() With {.Index = New UInt32Value(1UI)}).Append(New NumericValue(pointValue.ToString()))
            lineChartSeries.AppendChild(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values()).AppendChild(numLit)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a chart by examining the chart1.xml source, and building a method to replicate the XML structure. The class containing this method has local point variables for the start and finish of the data, and also the offset of the table in the worksheet.

I have no doubt this could be done more elegantly.

```
Private Sub GenerateChart(ByRef spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument, ByVal dataTable As System.Data.DataTable, ByVal docName As String, ByVal worksheetName As String) 

   Dim sheets As IEnumerable(Of Sheet) = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants(Of Sheet)().Where(Function(s) s.Name = worksheetName)

        Dim workSheetPart As WorksheetPart = CType(spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheets.First().Id), WorksheetPart)

        Dim drawingsPart As DrawingsPart = workSheetPart.AddNewPart(Of DrawingsPart)()
        workSheetPart.Worksheet.Append(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing() With {.Id = workSheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart)})
        workSheetPart.Worksheet.Save()

        Dim chartPart As ChartPart = drawingsPart.AddNewPart(Of ChartPart)()
        chartPart.ChartSpace = New ChartSpace()
        chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(New EditingLanguage() With {.Val = New StringValue("en-GB")})

        Dim chart As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart = chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart)(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart())
        Dim autoTitleDeleted As AutoTitleDeleted = chart.AppendChild(New AutoTitleDeleted() With {.Val = New BooleanValue(False)})
        Dim plotArea As PlotArea = chart.AppendChild(Of PlotArea)(New PlotArea())
        Dim layout As Layout = plotArea.AppendChild(Of Layout)(New Layout())

        Dim lineChart As LineChart = plotArea.AppendChild(New LineChart())
        Dim grouping As Grouping = lineChart.AppendChild(New Grouping() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of GroupingValues)(GroupingValues.Standard)})
        Dim smoooth As Smooth = lineChart.AppendChild(New Smooth() With {.Val = New BooleanValue(False)})

        For i As UInteger = 0UI To CUInt(dataTable.Rows.Count - 3) '-3?.... to remove table headers, totals, and the extra because 0 based index'

            Dim seriesName As String = dataTable.Rows(CInt(i))(0).ToString
            Dim lineChartSeries As LineChartSeries = lineChart.AppendChild(New LineChartSeries(New Index With {.Val = i}, New Order With {.Val = i}))
            Dim chartText As ChartText = lineChartSeries.AppendChild(New ChartText())

            Dim stringReference As StringReference = chartText.AppendChild(New StringReference())
            stringReference.AppendChild(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Formula() With {.Text = worksheetName + "!$" + GetXAxisName(CUInt(__rangeStart.X)) + "$" + (CUInt(__topRowOffset + __previousTableRowCount + i + 2)).ToString})

            Dim stringCache As StringCache = stringReference.AppendChild(New StringCache)
            stringCache.Append(New PointCount() With {.Val = 1})
            stringCache.AppendChild(New StringPoint() With {.Index = New UInt32Value(CUInt(0))}).Append(New NumericValue(seriesName))

            Dim marker As Marker = lineChartSeries.AppendChild(New Marker() With {.Symbol = New Symbol() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of MarkerStyleValues)(MarkerStyleValues.None)}})

            Dim categoryAxisData As CategoryAxisData = lineChartSeries.AppendChild(New CategoryAxisData())
            Dim catStringReference As StringReference = categoryAxisData.AppendChild(New StringReference)
            catStringReference.AppendChild(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Formula() With {.Text = worksheetName + "!$" + GetXAxisName(CUInt(__rangeStart.X) + 1UI) + "$" + (CUInt(__rangeStart.Y)).ToString + ":$" + GetXAxisName(CUInt(__rangeEnd.X) + 1UI) + "$" + (CUInt(__rangeStart.Y)).ToString})
            Dim catStringCache As StringCache = catStringReference.AppendChild(New StringCache(New PointCount() With {.Val = 12UI}))

            Dim values As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values = lineChartSeries.AppendChild(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values())
            Dim numberReference As NumberReference = values.AppendChild(New NumberReference())
            numberReference.AppendChild(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Formula() With {.Text = worksheetName + "!$" + GetXAxisName(CUInt(__rangeStart.X) + 1UI) + "$" + (i + 1UI + __topRowOffset).ToString + ":$" + GetXAxisName(CUInt(__rangeEnd.X) + 1UI) + "$" + (i + 1UI + __topRowOffset).ToString})
            Dim numberingCache As NumberingCache = numberReference.AppendChild(New NumberingCache(New FormatCode("General")))

            numberingCache.AppendChild(New PointCount() With {.Val = 12UI})

            Dim jUpper As UInteger = CUInt(dataTable.Columns.Count - 5)
            For j As UInteger = 1UI To jUpper

                Dim pointName As String = dataTable.Columns(CInt(j)).ColumnName
                Dim pointValue As Integer = CInt(dataTable.Rows(CInt(i))(pointName))

                Dim numericPoint As NumericPoint = catStringCache.AppendChild(New NumericPoint() With {.Index = New UInt32Value(j)})
                numericPoint.Append(New NumericValue(pointName))

                Dim numericValue As NumericPoint = numberingCache.AppendChild(New NumericPoint() With {.Index = New UInt32Value(j)})
                numericValue.Append(New NumericValue(dataTable.Rows(CInt(i))(CInt(j)).ToString()))

            Next j

        Next i

        lineChart.Append(New AxisId() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(48650112UI)})
        lineChart.Append(New AxisId() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(48672768UI)})

        Dim categoryAxis As CategoryAxis =
            plotArea.AppendChild(New CategoryAxis(
                                      New AxisId() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(48650112UI)} _
                                    , New Delete() With {.Val = False} _
                                    , New Scaling(
                                          New Orientation() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues)(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)}) _
                                        , New AxisPosition() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of AxisPositionValues)(AxisPositionValues.Bottom)} _
                                        , New TickLabelPosition() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of TickLabelPositionValues)(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo)} _
                                        , New CrossingAxis() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(48672768UI)}
                                    )
                                )

        Dim valueAxis As ValueAxis =
            plotArea.AppendChild(New ValueAxis(
                                      New AxisId() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(48672768UI)} _
                                    , New Delete() With {.Val = False} _
                                    , New Scaling(
                                          New Orientation() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues)(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)}) _
                                        , New AxisPosition() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of AxisPositionValues)(AxisPositionValues.Left)} _
                                        , New TickLabelPosition() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of TickLabelPositionValues)(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo)} _
                                        , New CrossingAxis() With {.Val = New UInt32Value(48650112UI)} _
                                        , New MajorGridlines()
                                    )
                                )
        Dim legend As Legend = chart.AppendChild(Of Legend)(New Legend(New LegendPosition() With {.Val = New EnumValue(Of LegendPositionValues)(LegendPositionValues.Right)}, New Layout()))
        chart.Append(New PlotVisibleOnly() With {.Val = New BooleanValue(True)})
        chartPart.ChartSpace.Save()
        drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = New WorksheetDrawing()

        Dim twoCellAnchor As TwoCellAnchor = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.AppendChild(Of TwoCellAnchor)(New TwoCellAnchor())
        twoCellAnchor.Append(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.FromMarker(New ColumnId("17"), New ColumnOffset("0"), New RowId("3"), New RowOffset("0")))
        twoCellAnchor.Append(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.ToMarker(New ColumnId("26"), New ColumnOffset("0"), New RowId("26"), New RowOffset("0")))

        Dim graphicFrame As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame = twoCellAnchor.AppendChild(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame)(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame())
        graphicFrame.Macro = ""
        graphicFrame.Append(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualDrawingProperties() With {.Id = New UInt32Value(2UI), .Name = "Chart 1"}, New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties()))
        graphicFrame.Append(New Transform(New Offset() With {.X = 0L, .Y = 0L}, New Extents() With {.Cx = 0L, .Cy = 0L}))
        graphicFrame.Append(New Graphic(New GraphicData(New ChartReference() With {.Id = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart)}) With {.Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart"}))
        twoCellAnchor.Append(New ClientData())

        drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Save()

    End Sub
```